# R - replacing column unique values with sequential primary key

Tags: python, r, dataframe

In R, I have a datatable, called "off", in the form of:

```
     callgroup agent_idx binary_outcome
1715         8       453              0
1716         5       486              0
1717        50       367              0
1718        60       513              0
1719         7       282              0
1720         8       660              0
```

For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I need a primary key for both callgroup and agent_idx that is sequential. I'd like the output to be as:

```
     callgroup agent_idx binary_outcome c_idx a_idx
1715         8       453              0     1    1
1716         5       486              0     2    2
1717        50       367              0     3    3
1718        60       513              0     4    4
1719         7       282              0     5    5
1720         8       660              0     1    6
```

I think this should be as easy as creating dummy variables, but I'm having an oddly hard time cracking this nut. So far, my strategy, which has failed, has been:

```
c_idx <- seq_along(unique(off$callgroup))
c_val <- unique(off$callgroup)

a_idx <- seq_along(unique(off$agent_idx))
a_val <- unique(off$agent_idx)

off2 <- off
off2$callgroup <-  replace(off$callgroup,c_val,c_idx)
off2$agent_idx <-  replace(off$agent_idx,a_val,a_idx)
```

Unfortunately, replace doesn't work this way; the second argument is a list of indices, and the third, the values to replace them with. I'm looking for a {A->B} swap.

In python, I could do this relatively simply:

```py
lookup = {elem:idx for idx,elem in enumerate(off['callgroup'].unique()}
off['c_id'] = off['callgroup'].apply(lambda x: lookup[x])
```

Of course, I'd have to repeat the process with the agents. But this is enough to demonstrate the concept I'm hoping to achieve. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `dplyr` approach using `cur_group_id` and previously formating the key variables in the order you wish. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(callgroup=factor(callgroup,levels = unique(callgroup),ordered = T),
         agent_idx=factor(agent_idx,levels = unique(agent_idx),ordered = T)) %>%
  group_by(callgroup) %>%
  mutate(id=cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% group_by(agent_idx) %>%
  mutate(id2=cur_group_id()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(callgroup=as.integer(as.character(callgroup)),
         agent_idx=as.integer(as.character(agent_idx)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  callgroup agent_idx binary_outcome    id   id2
      <int>     <int>          <int> <int> <int>
1         8       453              0     1     1
2         5       486              0     2     2
3        50       367              0     3     3
4        60       513              0     4     4
5         7       282              0     5     5
6         8       660              0     1     6
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(callgroup = c(8L, 5L, 50L, 60L, 7L, 8L), agent_idx = c(453L, 
486L, 367L, 513L, 282L, 660L), binary_outcome = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1715", "1716", 
"1717", "1718", "1719", "1720"))
```

Comment: Awesome, this was super helpful!